# Whats wrong? 'ifnull' is not a recognized built-in function name

Tags: sql-server-2008

Trying to get this query to work out, but i cant seem to find out whats wrong. Any help?

```
select s.IDENTIFIERS,
       s.store_id,
       ifnull(d.SALES_PRICE,ifnull(u.SALES_PRICE,s.SALES_PRICE)) as SALES_PRICE
       from BOOK_SALES as s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN store AS BV 
                    ON bv.store_id = s.store_id 
   left outer join discount as d
                on d.IDENTIFIERS=s.IDENTIFIERS
               and d.from_date<=s.sales_date
               and d.to_date>=s.sales_date
               and u.to_date<0>
   left outer join discount as u
                on u.IDENTIFIERS=s.IDENTIFIERS
               and u.to_date=0
```

Comment: Use `ISNULL()` for sql server.

Comment: Thanks, now im getting:[Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "u.to_date" could not be bound.

Comment: As @Michai says, you probably want `ISNULL` (if the 1st param is null, return the 2nd param, otherwise return the 1st param) but there is also `NULLIF` (if the 1st param and the 2nd param are the same, return `null`, otherwise return the 1st param)

Answer (score 4):

try this:

```
select s.IDENTIFIERS,
       s.store_id,
       isnull(d.SALES_PRICE,isnull(u.SALES_PRICE,s.SALES_PRICE)) as SALES_PRICE
       from BOOK_SALES as s
       LEFT OUTER JOIN store AS BV 
                    ON bv.store_id = s.store_id 
   left outer join discount as d
                on d.IDENTIFIERS=s.IDENTIFIERS
               and d.from_date<=s.sales_date
               and d.to_date>=s.sales_date
               and d.to_date='12/12/1989'
   left outer join discount as u
                on u.IDENTIFIERS=s.IDENTIFIERS
               and u.to_date='12/12/1989'
```

IFNULL is use in the My-sql not in sql server follow this link [null function in database](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_isnull.asp)

Comment: Thanks, getting: [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]Incorrect syntax near '>'.

Comment: Now its the same as over: [Err] 42000 - [SQL Server]The multi-part identifier "u.to_date" could not be bound.

Comment: change u to d in first one.

Comment: thanks, still getting errors tho.. [Err] 22018 - [SQL Server]Operand type clash: date is incompatible with tinyint // Should i use 0000 instead for setting unlimited date in my table ? or any other tip?

Comment: change 0 to particular date

Comment: It worked out when setting, '2099-01-01'.. But what is best practice for setting a unlimited date?

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/49297/discussion-between-pankeel-and-lebowski)